How to search folder/file in current explorer for VSCode
New feature for vscode (https://x.com/code/status/1845947961328410816).
So, currently when using ctrl/cmd + alt + F, we will search the file within this project. But, I want to search as previous, which means the matching folder/file will be highlighted in current explorer.
How to achieve this?
Thank you!
I try to modify <list.find>, but I don't know what should I do.
